# Why my view is not visible if I write code in my code behind in xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm writing code for my view in code behind. This is my code:

```cs
public class View1 : ContentView
{
    public View1()
    {
        Content = new StackLayout
        {
            Children = {
                new Label { Text = "CATEGORY 1", Margin = new Thickness(20, 0, 0, 10), TextColor = Color.Black, FontSize = 18, FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold }
            }
        };
        BoxView piece_ofLine = new BoxView
        {
            HeightRequest = 1,
            WidthRequest = 80,
            Color = Color.FromHex("#E0E0E0")
        };

        var grid = new Grid();
        grid.Margin = new Thickness(10, 0, 0, 0);
        grid.Padding = 0;
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(30) });
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1) });
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(30) });
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1) });
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(30) });
        grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1) });
        grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(40) });
        grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });

        var image1 = new Image { Source = "food1" };
        var label1 = new Label { Text = "Vendor Name 1" };
        BoxView piece_ofLine1 = new BoxView
        {
            HeightRequest = 1,
            WidthRequest = 80,
            Color = Color.FromHex("#E0E0E0")
        };
        var image2 = new Image { Source = "food1" };
        var label2 = new Label { Text = "Vendor Name 2" };
        BoxView piece_ofLine2 = new BoxView
        {
            HeightRequest = 1,
            WidthRequest = 80,
            Color = Color.FromHex("#E0E0E0")
        };
        var image3 = new Image { Source = "food1" };
        var label3 = new Label { Text = "Vendor Name 3" };
        BoxView piece_ofLine3 = new BoxView
        {
            HeightRequest = 1,
            WidthRequest = 80,
            Color = Color.FromHex("#E0E0E0")
        };
        grid.Children.Add(image1, 0, 0);
        grid.Children.Add(label1, 0, 1);
        Grid.SetColumnSpan(piece_ofLine1, 2);
        grid.Children.Add(piece_ofLine1, 1, 0);

        grid.Children.Add(image2, 0, 0);
        grid.Children.Add(label2, 0, 1);
        Grid.SetColumnSpan(piece_ofLine2, 2);
        grid.Children.Add(piece_ofLine2, 1, 0);

        grid.Children.Add(image3, 0, 0);
        grid.Children.Add(label3, 0, 1);
        Grid.SetColumnSpan(piece_ofLine3, 2);
        grid.Children.Add(piece_ofLine3, 1, 0);
        Content = grid;
    }
}
```

This is the UI I need

[image]

This is my view. As you can see only one image is visible over there-

[image]

I used to do design in XAML but since it is the content view I have to write the codes for design in code behind. So that's why I'm new to this. And I can't put the whole view inside the stack layout as we can do in XAML. This is the code for the view which I have written in XAML:

```xml
<StackLayout>
    <Label Text="CATEGORY 1" Margin="20,0,0,10" TextColor="Black" Font="Bold,18"/>
    <BoxView  Color="#E0E0E0" WidthRequest ="80" HeightRequest="1"/>

    <Grid  
        Margin="10,0,0,0"
         Padding="0"  
        >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
            <RowDefinition Height="1"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
            <RowDefinition Height="1"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
            <RowDefinition Height="1"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="foodimage1"/>
        <Label TextColor="Black" Text="Vendor Name 1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <BoxView  Color="#E0E0E0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
        <Image  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="foodimage2"/>
        <Label TextColor="Black" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="Vendor Name 2"/>
        <BoxView  Color="#E0E0E0" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
        <Image Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="foodimage3"/>
        <Label TextColor="Black" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Text="Vendor Name 3"/>
        <BoxView  Color="#E0E0E0" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
    </Grid>
    <Label Text="CATEGORY 2" Margin="20,0,0,10" TextColor="Black" Font="Bold,18"/>
    <BoxView  Color="#E0E0E0" WidthRequest ="80" HeightRequest="1"/>
    <Grid  
        Margin="10,0,0,0"
         Padding="0"  
        >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
            <RowDefinition Height="1"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
            <RowDefinition Height="1"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
            <RowDefinition Height="1"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="foodimage4"/>
        <Label TextColor="Black" Text="Vendor Name 1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
        <BoxView  Color="#E0E0E0"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
        <Image  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="foodimage5"/>
        <Label TextColor="Black" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="Vendor Name 2"/>
        <BoxView  Color="#E0E0E0"  Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
        <Image Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="foodimage6"/>
        <Label TextColor="Black" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Text="Vendor Name 3"/>
        <BoxView  Color="#E0E0E0"  Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
    </Grid>

</StackLayout>
```

I have to implement this same XAML code to C#. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can write your code in xaml for `ContentView` as well. When you add `ContentView` it comes with two files .xaml & .cs. Same as `ContentPage`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand this piece of code correctly, you are adding all the items on the same row:

```
grid.Children.Add(image1, 0, 0);
grid.Children.Add(label1, 0, 1);
Grid.SetColumnSpan(piece_ofLine1, 2);
grid.Children.Add(piece_ofLine1, 1, 0);

grid.Children.Add(image2, 0, 0);
grid.Children.Add(label2, 0, 1);
Grid.SetColumnSpan(piece_ofLine2, 2);
grid.Children.Add(piece_ofLine2, 1, 0);

grid.Children.Add(image3, 0, 0);
grid.Children.Add(label3, 0, 1);
Grid.SetColumnSpan(piece_ofLine3, 2);
grid.Children.Add(piece_ofLine3, 1, 0);
```

The Add method takes the view and then the column and row.

Right now, all your Add calls have the same values, so all elements will be placed in the same row. It should probably be more like this:

```
// Row 1
grid.Children.Add(image1, 0, 0);
grid.Children.Add(label1, 0, 0);
Grid.SetColumnSpan(piece_ofLine1, 2);
grid.Children.Add(piece_ofLine1, 1, 0);

// Row 2
grid.Children.Add(image2, 0, 1);
grid.Children.Add(label2, 0, 1);
Grid.SetColumnSpan(piece_ofLine2, 2);
grid.Children.Add(piece_ofLine2, 1, 1);

// Row 3
grid.Children.Add(image3, 0, 2);
grid.Children.Add(label3, 0, 2);
Grid.SetColumnSpan(piece_ofLine3, 2);
grid.Children.Add(piece_ofLine3, 1, 2);
```